# using helpers to shorten strftime in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

This is my first time attempting to use helpers. I want to put a relatively long method I keep reusing in my views into a helper.

An instance of the code in the view is here:

```
<%= @guide.date_starting.strftime("%B #{@guide.date_starting.day.ordinalize}") %> to 
<%= @guide.date_ending.strftime("%B #{@guide.date_ending.day.ordinalize}") %>
```

So what I have tried to do is write this in the module helper:

```
    def start_time_display
        self.strftime("%B #{@guide.date_starting.day.ordinalize}")
    end

    def end_time_display
        self.strftime("%B #{@guide.date_ending.day.ordinalize}")
    end
```

and then write this is in the views

```
<%= @guide.date_starting.start_time_display %> to <%= @guide.date_ending.end_time_display %>
```

which gives me this error:

```
undefined method `start_time_display' for Wed, 03 Sep 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time
```

So, how do I achieve this? Where am I going wrong? How could I write this better? Am I approaching helpers in the right way here? I have consulted the documentation and my understanding is this is what they are there for.

EDIT:

so i added Damien's answer,

View.html.erb

guide helper

```
def time_display(datetime)
  strftime("%B #{datetime.day.ordinalize}")
end


def time_display_span(start, end_date)
  time_display(start) + " to " + time_display(end_date)
end
```

error...

```
undefined method `strftime' for #<#<Class:0x000001088c0128>:0x000001088cb168>
```

Update: Damien was a lifesaver. His answer worked a treat and helped me understand. Kudos

Thanks in advance

Comment: @EgeErsoz It was in the right helper, i read that much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've slightly missed a fundamental concept.

```
@guide.date_starting.start_time_display
```

The above calls the method `start_time_display` on `date_starting`, which is a `DateTime` instance. Same as how `date_starting` is a method on `@guide`.

View helpers are like global functions, and so you would pass in your `@guide.date_starting` as an argument:

```
def time_display(datetime)
  datetime.strftime("%B #{datetime.day.ordinalize}")
end

def time_display_span(start_date, end_date)
  time_display(start_date) + " to " + time_display(end_date)
end
```

note: I have used a generic `time_display` because you can pass in `date_starting/date_ending` as an argument. I have also added a `time_display_span` which will further simplify your views:

```
<%= time_display_span(@guide.date_starting, @guide.date_ending) %>
```

Comment: Much better answer. Deleting mine.

Comment: @DamienRoche ok i think i get you, but your method gives me this error unexpected keyword_end def time_display_span(start, end) ^ /Users/Fred/projects/artsmill/artsmill/app/helpers/guides_helper.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' time_display(start) + " to " + time_display(end) ^

Comment: @rico_mac `end` is a reserved keyword. Don't fall into the habit of copy-pasting answers ;) use `end_date` instead. I'll update my answer, though.

Comment: Thanks @DamienRoche, I know, a wise man told me that once, I should listen more. I have, however adapted it and am still struggling to see the error, see update

Comment: @rico_mac I'm not too sure, then. Could you send over the full definitions for those methods (use pastie.org or something)? The syntax in my updated answer should be fine.

Comment: @rico_mac also, you might want to look into the Decorator pattern. I wouldn't use it in this case, but it can be a great alternative to model-specific view helpers. https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Comment: @DamienRoche, cool man. here you go. thanks for your help by the way.
http://pastie.org/9362160

Comment: @rico_mac is it still producing the same error as above? Maybe I'm too tired, but the syntax looks ok.

Comment: @DamienRoche yeah it is. if strftime is an undefined method does that mean I am calling it on something other than DateTime?

Comment: @rico_mac yes, most probably. It's a method on `DateTime`: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime. In the above `time_display` method, it should be called as `datetime.strftime(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56858/discussion-between-rico-mac-and-damien-roche).

Comment: @DamienRoche still unsure really.

Comment: @rico_mac sadly I'm on my way to bed, so can't chat. I'll check again on this tomorrow and talk further if you haven't resolved. However, the syntax looks ok. I've updated my answer, so give that a try. Because the method is quite general, it might be better put in `ApplicationHelper` than a `GuidesHelper`.

Comment: @rico_mac great to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

The stamp gem might do what you want.

https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp